# A normal operator is the continuous functional calculus of an adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a hilbert space and suppose $T \in B(H)$ is a normal operator. Is it true that there exist $S \in B(H)$ self-adjoint such that $T=f(S)$ being $f: \sigma(S) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function?

At the outset I thought the result was false for the following reason: if $H$ is separable then there exist a normal operator $T \in B(H)$  such that $\sigma(T)=K$, where
$$
K=\overline{\{ t+ i sin(1/t): t \in (0,1] \} }
$$
Therefore, if such an $S$ exist, we would have that
$$
K=\sigma(T)=\sigma(f(S))=f(\sigma(S))
$$
Since $\sigma(S) \subset \mathbb{R}$ (since $S$ is self-adjoint) this tells us that $K$ is the image of a continuous function $f: \sigma(S)\subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Writing $f$ as $f(t)=f_1(t)+if_2(t)$, the continuity of $f$ implies that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both continuous, also the definition of $K$ and the above equation tells us that $(0,1] \subset \sigma(S)$. Putting these facts together we would have that the function $g(t)=sin(1/t)$ can be extended to a continuous function $f_2$ defined on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (namely, $\sigma(S)$) which contains $(0,1]$ (and this isn't possible according to me).

However, in  the book *An Introduction to Operator Algebras* by *Kehe Zhu* it is claimed (without proof or hint) that the result is true.  That being said, these are my two questions:

1. What is wrong with the "counterexample" I provided?
2. How can I prove the claim? Any hint will be appreciated.

In advance thank you very much.

Comment: The only thing $f_2$ does is that it have to be a continuous map from $\sigma(S)$ onto $\overline{\{\sin(1/t): t \in (0, 1]\}}$. The latter set is just $[-1, 1]$ so there is no contradiction whatsoever. There’s no reason why $f_2$ has to extend the function $\sin(1/t)$.

Comment: The problem can be reduced to function spaces. By the Gelfand-Naimark theorem the unital $C^*$--algebra generated by $T$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C(\sigma(T)), $ and the operator $T$ corresponds to the multiplication by $z.$ The unital $C^*$-algebra generated by a selfadjoint operator $S$ is unitarily equivalent to $C(\sigma(S))$ where $S$ corresponds to multiplication by $t.$ The question is equivalent to the existence of a continuous function $f$ on $\sigma(S)\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t)=z$ and $f(\sigma(S))=\sigma(T).$

Comment: @DavidGao I see, you're right, thank you very much for the correction :)

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc It’s not just an issue of function spaces. You have to actually construct $S$ with the prescribed $\sigma(S)$ within $\mathbb{B}(H)$, not just find some $\sigma(S) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ with $f(\sigma(S)) = \sigma(T)$. The latter isn’t hard to achieve. It’s the former that requires a lot more efforts. Also, as I noted in the comments below my answer, $S$ cannot be constructed within $C(\sigma(T))$ in general.

Comment: @DavidGao According to OP the set $\sigma(S)$ is not prescribed. I do not claim that $f(\sigma(S))=\sigma(T)$ suffices. The multiplication by $z$ on $C(\sigma(T))$ must be obtained as $f(t),$ where $t$ is multiplication by the variable $t$ on $C(\sigma(S)).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I should clarify. What I meant is that it’s not clear what you meant when you said “The question is equivalent to the existence of a continuous function $f$ on $\sigma(S) \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t) = z$ and $f(\sigma(S)) = \sigma(T)$.” For one, we are trying to prove such an $S$ exists, not already given such an $S$, so it’s definitely not just about the existence of $f$. Also, $f(t) = z$ doesn’t make sense either. $f(t)$ is a function defined on $\sigma(S)$ while $z$ is a function defined on $\sigma(T)$. In what sense can they be equal?

Comment: @DavidGao What I mean is $f(M_t)=M_z,$ where $M_t$ and $M_z$ are multiplication operators on $C(\sigma(S))$ and $C(\sigma(T)),$ respectively.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Doesn’t that just have the same issue? $f(M_t)$ is an operator in $C(\sigma(S))$ and $M_z$ is an operator in $C(\sigma(T))$? You have to have an ambient algebra, namely $\mathbb{B}(H)$, that both $C(\sigma(S))$ and $C(\sigma(T))$ embed into, for this to make sense. And if that’s the case, I’m not sure how this can be called a reduction to function spaces.

Comment: @DavidGao Well. I am not excited about commutative von Neumann algebras. In the case of function spaces it suffices to consider bounded Borel functions.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Not sure about your points. To define Borel functional calculus you need a von Neumann algebra in the background. It’s not like you can define Borel functional calculus on $C(\sigma(T))$. You certainly can avoid talking about commutative vNa, as Martin did in his answer and I speculated in the comments below my answer, but vNa has to be featured somewhere (and effectively a commutative vNa will have to be hinted at, since that’s the range of Borel functional calculus, assuming the Hilbert space is separable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started to write yesterday a slightly more direct approach, that contains ideas mostly mentioned in the comments.

If we denote the Cantor set by $\def\cC{\mathcal C}\cC$ and by $f:\cC\to\sigma(T)$ a continuous Borel surjection (that exists by the universality of the Cantor set among compact metric spaces), [there exists a Borel right-inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3597025/22857) $g:\sigma(T)\to\cC$. We write
$$
T=\int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda\,dE(\lambda)
$$
via the Spectral Theorem, and we define
$$
S=\int_{\sigma(T)}g(\lambda)\,dE(\lambda). 
$$
The definition makes sense because $g$ is bounded Borel, and $S$ is selfadjoint because $g$ is real-valued. And by functional calculus we have $$f(S)=\int_{\sigma(T)}(f\circ g)(\lambda)\,dE(\lambda)=\int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda\,dE(\lambda)=T. 
$$

Comment: Very nice proof, thanks for sharing! :) I like it because it is accesible to anyone familiar with the spectral theorem. Again thanks for sharing!

Comment: My pleasure. This argument extends the obvious idea one would use in the discrete case.

Answer (score 3):

You've got some great answers for how to prove the claim already, but I wanted to elaborate on your "counterexample" a bit.

The only mistake with your counterexample is the insistence that $\sigma(S) = [0,1]$ with $f_2(t) = \sin(1/t)$.  The operator $S$ doesn't have to respect your construction/definition of $K$.  It's sufficient to find a Borel map $g: K \rightarrow \sigma(S) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and a continuous map $f: \sigma(S) \rightarrow K$ such that $f \circ g = \text{Id}_K$, which is what the other answers construct for you.

You're right that this would be impossible if we required $\sigma(S) = [0, 1]$!  Even if we're allowed to change our attempted mapping from the one you prescribed for $K$, the [Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz_theorem) says that $K$ isn't a continuous image of the unit interval.  That's because your $K$ is the [closed topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) which isn't locally connected.  So it's impossible to find a self-adjoint $S$ with spectrum $[0,1]$ that does the job.

The other answers show that if you let $\sigma(S)$ be, say, the Cantor set $\mathcal{C}$, then you can definitely make it work.  You can continuously map from $\mathcal{C}$ onto pretty much anything, including your topologist's sine curve.

So your counterexample was placing an artificial restriction on what the spectrum of $S$ could be, leading you to a mistaken conclusion.  If you only require $\sigma(S) \subset \mathbb{R}$ instead of $\sigma(S) = [0,1]$, it becomes doable.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for such a thorough explanation. I'll try to be careful with this kind of mistakes in the future. Again thank you and happy new year! :)

Answer (score 2):

The following proof uses quite advanced machinery - I'm sure there are more elementary proofs, but I can't come up with one.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the Cantor set. Since the Cantor set is universal among compact metrizable spaces, there exists a continuous surjection $f: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \sigma(T)$. This dualizes to an injective $\ast$-homomorphism $f^\ast: C(\sigma(T)) \rightarrow C(\mathcal{C})$. As $T$ is normal, we may let $\iota: C(\sigma(T)) \rightarrow \mathbb{B}(H)$ be the functional calculus map, which is an injective $\ast$-homomorphism. Let $A$ be the von Neumann algebra generated by $\iota(C(\sigma(T)))$, which is the same as the von Neumann algebra generated by $T$ and so in particular abelian. Then $\iota$ can be regarded as a $\ast$-homomorphism from $C(\sigma(T))$ to $A$. As abelian von Neumann algebras are injective in the category of unital abelian $C^\ast$-algebras and $\ast$-homomorphisms (see, for example, Theorem 2.4 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2995)), there exists a $\ast$-homomorphism $g: C(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow A$ s.t. $g \circ f^\ast = \iota$.

Now, let $x \in C(\mathcal{C})$ be the usual inclusion map $\mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In particular, $x$ is self-adjoint. Hence, $S = g(x)$ is a self-adjoint element of $\mathbb{B}(H)$. We claim that $f(S) = T$. Indeed, $f(S) = f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$ as $g$ is a $\ast$-homomorphism. But $f(x)$, as an element of $C(\mathcal{C})$, is simply $f^\ast(\mathrm{Id}_{\sigma(T)})$. Thus, $f(S) = g(f(x)) = g \circ f^\ast(\mathrm{Id}_{\sigma(T)}) = \iota(\mathrm{Id}_{\sigma(T)}) = T$. This proves the claim.

Comment: In case anyone is interested in finding a more elementary proof, let me make two comments: First, $S$ cannot be constructed by just applying continuous functional calculus to $T$. Indeed, assume $\sigma(T)$ has nonempty interior in $\mathbb{C}$. If for some continuous $g: \sigma(T) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $S = g(T)$ satisfies the requirement of the question, i.e., there exists continuous $f: \sigma(S) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $f(S) = T$, then $f \circ g = \mathrm{Id}_{\sigma(T)}$, so in particular $g$ is injective. Then $g$ restricted to the interior of $\sigma(T)$ is…

Comment: an injective continuous map from a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which is impossible per Invariance of domain. Second, the $S$ as constructed in my answer belongs to the von Neumann algebra generated by $T$. Hence, at least in case $H$ is separable, $S$ can be constructed using Borel functional calculus. As such, an elementary proof would probably consist of showing that, for any compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$. There exists a Borel $g: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which admits a continuous left inverse $f: \overline{g(K)} \rightarrow K$.

Comment: In fact, if I’m not mistaken, the continuous surjection $f: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow K$ constructed here (https://imgur.com/a/UDgthQm) admits a Borel right inverse $g: K \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. So that would be enough. But I’d rather not go through all the efforts required to check all the details. I’ll leave that to other people.

Comment: thank you very much, I haven't seen Von Neumann algebras yet so this proof is a little cryptic for me but I will check it carefully :), again thank you.

Comment: The other approach you mentioned seems more "friendly" though, although the first one you provided seems certainly the most elegant proof.

Comment: @ferolimen The approach I mentioned in comments can probably be checked as long as you know Borel functional calculus. It’s a more hands-on proof. The approach in the answer seems overkill and overly abstract even to myself. The fact that abelian von Neumann algebras are injective in the category of unital abelian $C^\ast$-algebras and $\ast$-homomorphisms, for example, is very obscure.

Comment: David's comments about the "more elementary proof" are interesting in the context of Zhu's book.  It seems like the exercise only expects you to know about the continuous functional calculus (it's at the end of that section), but we needed at least the Borel functional calculus to get our self-adjoint operator.  I wonder if that's an oversight on Zhu's part.  It would be interesting if he had some other approach in mind.

Comment: @JoshKeneda That is strange. Both spectral theorem and Borel functional calculus are only mentioned so much later in the book. I struggle to see how knowledge of continuous functional calculus alone would be enough to prove this given my first comment. Perhaps the author was thinking about compact operators when he made the exercise?